# Symfony2 Exception class, Why use throw new $class?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm looking at Symfony2 classes and I found something like this

```
try {
            return $this->parseSelectorGroup($stream);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $class = get_class($e);

            throw new $class(sprintf('%s at %s -> %s', $e->getMessage(), implode($stream->getUsed(), ''), $stream->peek()), 0, $e);
        }
```

Why they use

```
        $class = get_class($e);

        throw new $class
```

such syntax. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: You should have added as well from which file and which line you got that otherwise answers might be pretty broad.

Comment: `symfony2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/CssSelector/CssSelector.php` line 99-105

Comment: Ah the broken CSSSelector parser. That is to handle parsing errors that are expressed via exceptions, so the code want's to preserve the message but extend it with more debug information. It can be the case - but I do not *know* that - that some parsing information is signalled via exceptions which could be a smell. The parser docks on top of the scanner and does this on the fly IIRC. You find an alternative CSSSelector parser here: https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/PhpCss which is currently alpha but follows the standards and does not stop on half way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not the original author of that line of code so I can only *assume* why this was done.

As the code shows, the standard message of the exception is being extended with additional information of the string handling class (getUsed, peek - sounds like a stream buffer/parser/scanner/peeker).

The Message is edited and then a new object of the same class is being thrown.

*Generally:* When you have a class name in a variable and want to create a new instance of that class, you can simply use:

```
$className = "ClassName";
$instance = new $className();
```

This is done here with the catched exceptions classname, see [`get_class`](http://php.net/get_class).

*Further Note:* This code is conceptually broken because it uses a class with an undefined interface for it's constructor. It then makes use of the constructor function without knowing anything about it's constructor.

There might be some information hidden that such a case is not to be expected to happen though. So this is merely a further note. You should have concrete reasons to do something like that, so this has been done for a reason and there might be some design decision which is not documented by the some lines of code you've posted. So handle with care.